# NotFound in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to CakePHP, in this project, there's a route like

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

If I access `http://localhost/`, it will display the content of view

but if I change it to

```
Router::connect('/asdf', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

and access `http://localhost/asdf`, it will tell 404 not found.

I search a lot, and don't know why

sample code here:

https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-ex

Comment: Might be you are missing view file in your index action. echo and exit something in index action and check whether its display, if yes then view is not defined issue, else its routing issue

Comment: If a view was not defined, it would not give a 404, it would throw a missing view exception. Please post the actual error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in end of your routes.php file.

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```